# Getting different Azure AD Connect sync states through admin portal and Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When requensting https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization with the specific Bearer token, i get the response: "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null, "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null

[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqx59.png)

But in the Azure Active Directory admin center the ***Sync Status*** is *Enabled* and ***Last Sync*** Less than 1 hour ago

[Azure Active Directory admin center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVDc4.png)

Do anyone have an idea why its representing me two different states?

Comment: When did you sync your Azure AD from an on-premises directory for the first time? There may be a delay. Also check the sync status from O365 admin center: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/view-directory-synchronization-status.

Comment: Any updates? Does this issue still exist?

Comment: @AllenWu thank you for your reply. yeah the issue still exists. The first sync was several months ago, so it shouldn't be that delay. 
I tried this manual but on the "Directory Synchronization pane" i get the message that i should use the ‎Azure Active Directory‎ Connect-Tool instead and nothing like "Go to DirSync management".